# Migrating drupal site from a Windows to a Linux machine

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I had to migrate a drupal site from a Windows machine running the xampp package to a machine running Linux (Ubuntu 10.04).

I exported the database to a sql file on the source machine and recreated the database using the file on the destination machine. Also, i copied my website folder from the source to the destination. I also made the hostname,username and password changes in settings.php to reflect the mysql credentials on the destination machine,but when i try to access the site, i get the message **'Error connecting to mysql'**.

What could be going wrong here ?

Comment: Does the database have the exact same name?

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should have something to do with programming (i.e. writing code). For general help with administering your website, check [Pro Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

I would start over and install Drupal from scratch.  You can leave all of your files alone, but get rid of sites/default/settings.php.  Then run the /install.php script so that you know you're getting a proper DB connection.  After you get back to square 1, then try bringing in your old DB.  It's a PITA, but migrating Drupal sites tends to be.

The [Backup and Migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) can be really helpful in situations like yours.  Try installing it on your dev site, run the backup, and then reinstall your staging site from scratch, install backup_migrate and then restore from there.

Answer (score 0):

SSH to your web server and do

```
mysql -u username -h hostname -p
```

Can you connect using that? If that doesn't work, then it's something with your database server configuration. If that works, then it's something with your Drupal configuration.

What about

```
mysql -u username -h hostname -p databasename
```

If that works, try `SHOW TABLES;` to see if there's anything in there.

Comment: Yes,mysql -u username -h hostname -p works,so the username, password and hostname are correct.Im unable to figure out what could be the problem with the Drupal config, because i have copied the site as is. It is working on the Windows machine,and i havent made any changes apart from settings.php on the destination Linux machine ! :(

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you go the right syntax 
$db_url = 'mysqli://root:pass1@localhost/drupaldb'

and you have no prefix config.. i have moved many db and they all worked

.. are you sure you are using a standard port and there are no firewall issues

username:password@host:port/databasename

Comment: Thanks for the reply...what is prefix config ?

Comment: in the settings.php just bellow the db setting